# PHP Code is not Running

Tags: php, apache

I have some PHP source code to download email from GoDaddy server.

It is properly running on my system with Fedora and XAMPP with `PHP 5.4.17`. I have hosted same code in CentOS with `PHP 5.3.3`, but it is not running. It is not showing any errors. I started googling about this.

Later, I discovered that some configuration is needed in `php.ini`. I am using IMAP in my source code. I think it is because of this that it is not running.

```
$server = '{imap.secureserver.net:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
```

How can I configure this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On CentOS you should enable `extension=php_imap.so` because it's a Linux platform.

Check if it's correctly loaded in a page with `<? phpinfo(); ?>`.

Here is some stuff you can check :

- Do you resolv imap.secureserver.net on your hosting?
- Are you allowed to connect to distant server? Does your PHP configuration allow it? Does GoDaddy allow it?
- Maybe some [imap_open](http://php.net/imap_open) is not allowed
- Does `imap.secureserver` allow connections from your hosting?
- Check for firewalls

Comment: Thanks.... i have installed imap using 'yum install php-imap'. Now its working fine.